# Why does the program crash?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to implement a program that firstly checks if a head node has been created yet for a linked list. if not it proceeds to create that list. After creating one, the user has an option to update the nodes in that list.

And the user then gets to display the list if she/he chooses to do so.

I am a beginner and completely self-taught in programming, and I can't seem to comprehend linked lists that well, so I'm hoping I can get feedback.

The error reads:

```
Please enter your pin number: 1234
-----------------------------------
Process exited after 58.62 seconds with return value 3221225477
press any key to continue . . .

finalprojectiter1.exe has stopped working
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: finalprojectiter1.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5e569603
  Fault Module Name:    msvcrt.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.7601.17744
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4eeb033f
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000000623ec
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a69b
  Additional Information 2: a69b958c33445d155cf25b656547ecca
  Additional Information 3: 873b
  Additional Information 4: 873b5488bb4a3eacc70f3fe2969bdb0f
```

**EDIT**

the following code now works:

'''

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct node{
    char *name, *status;
    int pin_num;
    float money;
    struct node *next; 
    }node;

    int main(){
        node *p = NULL, *temp = NULL, *head = NULL; 
        char name[30];
        char response;
        char status[20];
        int pin_num=0, i=0;
        float money =0;
        while (1)
        {
            if (head == NULL) 
            {
                    printf("Would you like to register? [Y,y] or [N,n]\n");
                    scanf("%c", &response);
                    if (response == 'N' || response == 'n')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    printf("Enter a value for your card number: ");
                    scanf("%d", &pin_num);
                    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                    temp->pin_num = pin_num;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    head = temp;
                    p = head;

                    for(i = 1 ; i<4; i=i+1 )
                    {
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        printf("Enter value for the money: ");
                        scanf("%f", &money);
                        temp = ((node*)malloc(sizeof(node)));
                        temp->money = money;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        p->next =temp;
                        p=p->next; 
                    }
                    else if (i == 2)
                    {
                        printf("Enter your name: ");
                        scanf("%s", &name);
                        temp = ((node*)malloc(sizeof(node)));
                        temp->name = name;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        p->next =temp; 
                        p=p->next; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Enter your status: ");
                        scanf("%s", &status);
                        temp = ((node*)malloc(sizeof(node)));
                        temp->status = status;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                        p->next =temp; 
                        p=p->next; 
                    }

                    printf("\n");
                    printf("The registration is complete.");

                    }
                    continue;
                    }
            }
            else 
            {
                    while(1)
                    {
                    printf("card details:             | press [1]\n");
                    printf("update card details:      | press [2]\n");
                    printf("choose destinations:      | press [3]\n");
                    printf("Input money in the card:  | press [4]\n");
                    printf("leave:                    | press [5]\n");
                    scanf("%d", &i);
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        p = head;
                        printf("%d \t", p->pin_num);
                        p=p->next;
                        printf("%.2f \t", p->money);
                        p=p->next;
                        printf("%s \t", p->name);
                        p=p->next;
                        printf("%s \t", p->status);
                        p=head; 
                        continue;
                    } 
                    else if (i == 2)
                    {
                        printf("card name:                | press [1]\n");
                        printf("card status:              | press [2]\n");
                        printf("card pin number:          | press [3]\n");
                        scanf("%d", &i);
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            printf("Enter a new name: \t");
                            scanf("%s", name);
                            p=head;
                            p = p->next->next;
                            p->name = name;
                            p=head;
                            printf("\nupdate successful");
                        }
                        else if (i == 2)
                        {
                            printf("Enter a new status: \t");
                            scanf("%s", status);
                            p=head;
                            p = p->next->next->next;
                            p->status = name;
                            p=head;
                            printf("\nupdate successful");
                        }
                        else if (i == 3)
                        {
                            printf("Enter a new pin: \t");
                            scanf("%d", &pin_num);
                            p=head;
                            head->pin_num = pin_num;
                            printf("\nupdate successful");
                        }
                        continue;

                    }
                    else if (i == 3)
                    {
                        printf("function unwritten");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (i == 5)
                    {
                            break;
                    }

                    }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Put each of your declarations `node *p = NULL, *temp = NULL, *head = NULL;`  on separate lines.

Comment: What is your input? Did you use your debugger?

Comment: @Fidding Bits i edited the post above.

Comment: I don't understand reason of `for(i = 1 ; i<4; i=i+1 )`

Comment: In one of the first scanf you forget to put `&` before the variable. Also `temp` is null when you try to write in it.

Comment: Have a look at the errors here: https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/Enter-your-Pin-Number

Comment: (Press the Run button)

Comment: Basically, you need to put `&` in front of your `scanf` variables, *except* for the `char` array variables.

Comment: OMG! Sorry guys. After reading all of your inputs I have went back and changed them all. It was the little things like not putting &..... I have since changed the code. And now it works. I wonder, is there any good way (practice) that programmers do to not get confused with the placment of brackets when the program is too difficult or too long to read?

Comment: `scanf("%d", pin_num);` -`scanf("%d", &pin_num);`, didn't you get compiler warnings such as `scanf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'`? They are there for a reason.

Comment: @Jabberwocky hi! I am not sure how the compiler works for DevC, but for some reason it allowed me to run the program after compiling it. it said there were 0 errors

Comment: @snr hi! It's basically a for loop to create the remaining nodes after the head. although as you can see, i basically wrote the codes to create the nodes as if there 
 wasn't a need for the for loop...I did this because i couldn't think of a way to add make the nodes have different data types like int->string->int etc....

Comment: You experienced [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: this is a bit off topic, but I want to modularize the update part by making a seperate function for it. How could I pas the linked list as a parameter for the update function and is there a sort of return type in this situation?

Comment: @RogerSNITH that's another question, therefore you should ask a new question.